# Change the editor in the View command called by TeX-command-master

Tags: auctex

The first `C-c C-c` by default suggests to run LaTeX command, and the second suggests View. The latter, in its turn suggest me a command to run the viewer, and I always have to change the editor to `zathura`. I’d want to make emacs stop asking and do `LaTeX` whenever I press `C-c C-c` and run `View` whenever I pass `C-c C-v`, since it doesn’t seem to do anything to me right now. Also I’d want to set up the default command for running the viewer, but I couldn’t find it. The `LaTeX` and the `View` commands are set in AUCTeX group under ‘Tex Command List’, and when we go down to the description of the `View` command we see

```
Name: View
        Command: %V
```

Oh wow.

The expansion of `%V` is defined below Tex Command List, under Tex Expand List, and here we see…

```
 Key: %V
            Expander: 
(lambda nil
  (TeX-source-correlate-start-server-maybe)
  (TeX-view-command-raw))
```

`M-x describe-function RET TeX-view-command-raw` says

```
TeX-view-command-raw is a compiled Lisp function in `tex.el'.
(TeX-view-command-raw)
Choose a viewer and return its unexpanded command string.
```

So I have to somehow replace it with the actual command I want, a-and… How do I actually do that? Excuse me, I am aware of that that’s being very silly of me trying to do something with Emacs without a firm grasp of elisp, but how do I do that? Why isn’t there a filed for a command like Latex Command has?

Comment: I cannot understand: do you want to set the default viewer to be opened with `C-c C-v`?  If so, you have to customize the variable [`TeX-view-program-selection`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dview_002dprogram_002dselection)

Comment: @giordano, Ironically, I’ve found it in my init.el. I must note, that it’s impossible to alter from within emacs, since the viewer is to be chosen from a selection menu after M-x customize-variable. Also %V thing got replaced with a normal replaceable command once I restarted emacs daemon. I don’t know what changed it, I didn’t update the emacs package since the daemon start.

Comment: If you want to add a viewer not already present in `TeX-view-program-selection` you have to add it to [`TeX-view-program-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dview_002dprogram_002dlist) (variable mentioned in the documentation of `TeX-view-program-selection`)